# WordPress: Create a page template with No Footer

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to create a page template that doesn't use footer. Removing `get_footer()` will not work in this case. Because my theme adds the stylesheets and scrtipts after the footer (before /body) and if I remove `get_footer()` all the scripts and styles are not loaded which will mess up css styling on the page.

I tried to create a separate file footer-none.php without footer area elements and used `get_footer(none)`;. But this is not working.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
get_footer();
```

With this:

```
wp_footer();
```

That should trigger the scripts, etc. without needing an actual `footer.php` file.

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer

Answer (score 0):

Or in **footer-none.php** put

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This is the hook used to load your JS etc. from the footer.